# How to make sense of the Euler Lagrange equations for an infinite action?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sg.symplectic-geometry, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics

The Euler–Lagrange equation is an equation satisfied by a function  $q$, which is a stationary point of the functional

$S(\boldsymbol q) = \int_a^b L(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t))\, \mathrm{d}t$

Say we have an infinite action over infinite time - the action of a free particle for all time, for example. A critical point of the action functional means nothing here, but of course the Euler Lagrange equations still exist for all time.  If we associate the Euler Lagrange equations to a Hamiltonian system, then the path should solve Hamiltons equations iff the Euler Lagrange equations are satisfied. Can we say that these still offer a solution as $t \rightarrow \infty$, even though asking about "a critical point of the action functional" no longer makes sense? Is there a way to make sense of it formally?

(I originally asked this on mathstackexchange but didn't receive a satisfactory response. I tried to migrate it but could not)

Comment: Critical when restricted to any compact domain (i.e. on closed intervals).

Comment: Of course it makes sense. The solution would be a path which minimizes the action functional for each compact time interval. You have to pay attention to boundary effects: Look at variations which vanish at the boundary, or more general variations. A model for this is the way geodosics are derived in Riemannian geometry. It may happen that the path runs out of the space in finite time.

Comment: If you want, you can also "renormalise" by changing the Lagrangian to one that makes the action finite for a given solution (The ELE are the same for $L$ and for $\tilde L = L+g(t)$ for any function $g$). In the example of a free particle with $L(q,\dot q)=\frac12 \dot q^2$, you could replace that with $\tilde L=L-\frac12v^2$ and get that $\tilde S$ is finite for any $q(t)$ such that $q(t)=vt+a+\eta(t)$, where $\eta=0$ outside a finite interval.

Comment: Crossposted from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2651652/11127